# .map() Method on ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Is it possible to map another Postgres database table into the existing mapping shown on this code? Preferable would be as some kind of an array function.

```
 {todos.map(todo => (
                    <tr key={todo.lists_id} key={starting.route_id}>
                        <td></td>
                        <td>{todo.description}</td>

                        <td>
                            <EditTrip todo={todo} />
                        </td>
                        <td><button className="btn btn-danger" onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.lists_id)}>Delete</button></td>
                    </tr>
                ))}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you mean by adding another table to this method? Do you mean if it's possible to add a table header?

Comment: Do you mean moving table to separate component (which is definitely makes sense)?

Comment: @Peter Yes :) is there a way to do this? I want Destination to show its on table from lists_id and Start to show its on table from route_id.

Comment: @StudioMan can you elaborate what problem do you have, then? You already have a similar approach with <EditTrip />

Comment: @Peter First of when i submit the data from the client-side I get an ID on the Database table but its not displaying any table data on the application on what I have typed before sending. The backend works for the API since I have tested it on Postman. I could post the whole three pages of the MVC but I don't wanna tire you out :)

Comment: @StudioMan Sorry, I'm lost completely after your last comment. Maybe you can provide input data and expected result?

Comment: @Peter sorry Peter i know its confusing, i will post the input data here today. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Is that what are you looking for?

```
const ToDoItem = ({ todo, deleteTodo }) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <td>{todo.description}</td>
      <td>
        <EditTrip todo={todo} />
      </td>
      <td>
        <button
          className="btn btn-danger"
          onClick={() => deleteTodo(todo.lists_id)}
        >
          Delete
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  );
};
...
const ListItems = () => {
  retrun (
      ...  
        <tbody>
          {todos.map((todo) => (
            <ToDoItem key={todo.lists_id} deleteTodo={deleteTodo} />
          ))}
        </tbody>
      ...
  );
}
```